# How to open Tkinter programs nicely?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

When I opened a Tkinter program, 3 things are opening:

1. My program
2. IDLE (shell)
3. Black screen (python command line)

How can I block second and third ones for a clean view? Thanks.

Comment: could you next time you ask something, that is related to the OS post which os you use? I suppose you're using windows because i only discovered this problem with windows, but it would be better if you would post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TkinterProgram.py file runs on console basis that is using command prompt or terminal and TkinterProgram.pyw file is used when you are building a GUI application and not a console application.

`.py` **for building console application**

`.pyw` **for building GUI application**

In other words just add `.pyw` extension to your existing application and run it with double click, that way you will hide IDLE, command prompt/terminal.

Source: http://filext.com/file-extension/PYW